# PhpMyAdmin, where procedures are saved on filesystem

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I want to create procedure in mysql over phpmyadmin which insert paramters in two tables but phpmyadmin throws error that this is not possible.

So i want to try edit procedures over notepad++. Can you please tell me where are they saved on file system.

I run phpmyadmin on localhost with xampp.

Or if any other option to create procedure with this two insert statement.

```
INSERT INTO `table1`(`att1`, `att2`, `att3`) 
VALUES (p_att1, p_att2, p_att3);
INSERT INTO `table2`(`att1`, `att2`, `att3`, `att4`, `att5`)
VALUES ('admin','admin', p_att4, p_att5, p_att6)
```

Comment: You should at least specify mysql version you are using. If you are referring to stored procedures they are stored in mysql database, but it might be that you are using old version which has no support for procedures.

Comment: PHPMYADMIN -  4.0.4.1    
MYSQL- libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.10

Comment: "throws error that this is not possible" ... could you perhaps include the error?  Procedures are not stored "on the filesystem" in raw form.  They are stored by the server in a table, and you do not want to try to manipulate those structures.  Also, the version of your mysql server is found with the query SELECT @@VERSION; ... neither of the numbers you posted is your server version.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in comments stored procedures are not stored on the filesystem but rather in a special table in a database itself.

If you have appropriate permissions you can see a procedure's definition by issuing the following [command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-create-procedure.html)

```
SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc;
```

Now your procedure can look like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc
(
  IN _att1 VARCHAR(32), 
  IN _att2 VARCHAR(32),
  IN _att3 VARCHAR(32),
  IN _att4 VARCHAR(32),
  IN _att5 VARCHAR(32)
)
BEGIN
  START TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO table1(att1, att2, att3) 
      VALUES (_att1, _att2, _att3);
    INSERT INTO table2(att1, att2, att3, att4, att5)
      VALUES ('admin','admin', _att3, _att4, _att5);
  COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8d70/1)** demo